# Want to remove Unlock login key ring when no keyring directory is there?

Tags: login, password, keyrings, unlock

Recently I lost my root user password. So I had reset it using the Recovery terminal.
Now whenever I login, the Ubuntu shows a dialogue box with unlock keyring. I already tried for deleting the keyring folder in the .gnome2 folder but there is no folder related to keyring or anything.

Comment: You see there is the problem. There is nothing to edit or do right click on... if i try to make a new keyring named as login it hangs up. Even the folder in gnome2. doesn't has any folder named keyring or login rather it is empty...

Comment: When I open passwords and keys, there is no key or keyring or tabs. though there is an option adding a keyring and others.
So you see there is nothing to change.

Comment: What if you don't know the original user password, which was the reason for the change in the 1st place? You can't add a new password. Tks

Answer (score 2):

The answer is provided in Ubuntu One help faq. The link is [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-keyring-password-prompt/).

That says:

1. Open Applications->Accessories->Passwords And Encryption Keys or on
   Ubuntu 11.04 or greater press the "super key" (Windows key on most keyboards)
   and type "Passwords" then click on "Passwords and Encryption Keys"
2. Right-click on the "Passwords" folder and select "Change Password"
3. Set the new keyring password to be the same as your login password.

Alternatively, if you don't know the old password at step 2.

2. Right-click on the "Passwords" entry and select "Delete".
3. Now create a new "Passwords" entry and give it a password (likely the same as your login for simplest usage.)

Comment: Have you changed your keyring password to login password?

Answer (score 1):

For others coming across this from Google who have a fully encrypted hard drive and want to remove the passwords here is an alternative.

This will disable the key ring prompt by removing the password.

Set the key ring to no password.

1. Press super key, or click launcher orb, enter password and select "Passwords and Keys" when it comes up
2. Right click "Login" for Passwords section
3. Follow the prompts and set an empty password
4. Accept the prompt for storing keys/data unencrypted

I do realize some people are gonna jump all over this answer, but if you have your entire hard drive encrypted with LUKS, then the data is already encrypted and the drive unlocked/decrypted during startup prompt.

If you're like me and prefer your drive encrypted, then typing both the drive encryption password and then a login password is redundant and annoying.

Some references:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/disable-unlock-login-keyring-ubuntu-13-04/

[How secure is an encrypted LUKS filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97196/how-secure-is-an-encrypted-luks-filesystem)